# how to get selected item in combobox within datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn, datagridviewcombobox

I have a window form, in which there are a no of textboxes, other control and a `datagrid view`.
Datagrid view have 3 column. one colume is bind with `combobox` and two other with textboxes.
Data comes in combobox is bind from a table. Table name is account table.On Button click, Data saved in two tables.

Both table name is `Register table` and `detail table`.There is 1 to many relationship between `Register` and `detail table`
Normal textboxes and other controls data save in Register table and datagridview data i.e combobox and two textboxes data save in detail table.All things is going well on insert button click.

When we comes on that window form for edit/update data. Then we fetch data from both tables. all data is shown correctly in their respected controls.
But the combobox within datagridview is not showing selected data where as 
two textboxes within gridview also shown correct data.

My problem is that how to show selected column data from detail
table in combobox list which is bind with Account table.

One more thing i want to tell that i insert account name not account id in detail table during inserting process.
That is the problem

Comment: Do you want to select an item in the combobox?

Comment: Thanks Weilah for your Reply. Actually My Issue is solve now. The Problem is with Inserting Data in Detail table. Actually i am insert account name in my table whereas binding combobox with displaymember with account name and valuemember with accountid. the problem is with valuemember. now i bind valuemember aslo with accountname. and now my problem is solve